# outOfBoundException while parsing string in java

Tags: java

I am facing one issue in parsing,
I have one String as: `String str="20|^64|^New Income - GROWTH|^10.0|^27-Dec-2011"`

I want to parse this with delimiter"|^".

I had tried it as:

```
ArrayList<String> stocklist = IOUtil.parseResponse(str, "|^");
```

here is parseResponse() method:

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseResponse(String input, String delimeter) {
    ArrayList<String> parsed_strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (true) {
        int i = input.indexOf(delimeter);
        if (i >= 0) {
            String s = input.substring(0, i);
            parsed_strings.add(s.trim());
            input = input.substring(i + delimeter.length(), input.length());
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (parsed_strings.size() < 1) {
        parsed_strings.add(input);
    }
    return parsed_strings;
}
```

But I am not getting last element `27-Dec-2011` . I am getting outOfBoundException as: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4`

any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the size is 4, the indexes are from 0 to 3.

Comment: @MarounMaroun. But I want that last element also "27-Dec-2011" how I will get that.

Comment: Do you want to split the string with |^ delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String []b = "20|^64|^New Income - GROWTH|^10.0|^27-Dec-2011".split("\\|\\^");
for (String a: b) {
   System.out.println(a);
}
```

Prints:

```
20
64 
New Income - GROWTH
10.0
27-Dec-2011
```

You date string is then `b[4]`;

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you're approaching this problem wrong, you want an ArrayList of the strings delimited by |^.  I would just do this:

```
ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\\|\\^")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only adding the substrings to the array which end with `|^`. If you put an additional `|^` at the end of the string everything will be fine. Or change the code so that it always adds the remaining part (behind the last delimiter) of the string. Like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseResponse(String input, String delimeter) {
    ArrayList<String> parsed_strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = -1;
    while ((i = input.indexOf(delimeter)) >= 0) {
        String s = input.substring(0, i);
        parsed_strings.add(s.trim());
        input = input.substring(i + delimeter.length(), input.length());
    }
    parsed_strings.add(input);
    return parsed_strings;
}
```

But the best thing would be to use the [String split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

For example like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseResponse(String input, String delimeter) {
    String quotedDelimiter = Pattern.quote(delimeter);
    String[] outputArray = input.split(quotedDelimiter);
    List<String> outputList = Arrays.asList(outputArray);
    return new ArrayList<String>(outputList);
}
```

It looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Issue probably is here;

```
input = input.substring(i + delimeter.length(), input.length());
```

[substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

> public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                  int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified **beginIndex** and extends to the character at
>   index **endIndex - 1**. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and did not get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Instead, the method returns the array ["20", "64", "New Income - GROWTH", "10.0"].

To fix your code to include the last element, change this snippet:

```
if (parsed_strings.size() < 1) {
    parsed_strings.add(input);
}
```

to this new snippet:

```
parsed_strings.add(input);
```

Comment: Btw, "delimeter" is spelled "delimiter".

Answer (score 0):

this is because you stop at the last index of |^ which is before 27-Dec-2011 
You should either change algorithm or have |^ at end of string